# Catching memcache exception in java

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I am using spymemcached-2.8.4.jar and jdk.1.7.

Here is my code

```
try {

     MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient(...);

     client.set('name', 1000, 'some_name');

}catch(Exception ex){
     System.out.println("Exception occurred");
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     ex.printStackTrace();

     logExceptionInDB(ex);
}
```

In my scansion, my memcached machine is not running, so it is printing the following exception in console,

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:369)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:242)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:836)
```

**But I want to catch this excepting to write it in database. How to catch this exception?**

Comment: You **are** catching the exception... Just handle it the way you want.

Comment: Does your console print  - "Exception occurred"??
If it does, then you are already catching the exception, use JDBC connector  to connect to DB and persist the error message(ex.getMessage()).

Comment: No actually, actually its an asynchronous call, implemented using FutureTask. Inside the invoked thread, it is printing exception, no throwing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't catch the exception mentioned in the post, as it was already catch by spymemcached itself, you can only see the log, the related code in `MemcachedConnection.java` is :

```
catch (ConnectException var5) {
            this.getLogger().info("Reconnecting due to failure to connect to %s", new Object[]{node, var5});
            this.queueReconnect(node);
        }
```

It will try to reconnect afterwards, so make sure your configuration is right.
**Actually, you can catch exception produced by `set` method:**

```
    OperationFuture<Boolean> future = client.set("name", 1000, "some_name");
    Boolean result = future.get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Assume that your timeout time for one operation is 50 milliseconds, you will get `CheckedOperationTimeoutException` after the time elapsed.